# Social Login Plugin for Wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins, oauth, oauth-2.0

Iv seen answers on this but they all are from at least 2 years ago (that i saw) and none of the remedies worked for me.

I am using the Yith Social Login for Woocommerce, I go to sign in and test and keep getting this error message:
 "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs."

I've white listed every thing i possibly can think of, nothing works.

I am using 0Auth as well (not even sure if its needed)

Anyone got the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is the plugin doesn't declare the correct redirect url you have defined inside it.

I tried adding this to Facebook valid redirect url and it finally worked:

http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-login/hybridauth/

That's what the plugin is redirecting to, and what Facebook try to compare with your valid url redirection.

Comment: THIS THE CORRECT SOLUTION as of today, Feb 2018. Please note that the default out-of-the-box Wordpress Social Login DOES NOT FUNCTION for Facebook login until you complete this step. it should be in the instructions

Comment: Slightly different in my case: `http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-login/hybridauth/?hauth_done=Facebook`

Added `?hauth_done=Facebook` QS. It is unclear if this is because we are using more than one social service for login or not, but the query string was required at least for me

Comment: @MattRabe adding "?hauth_done=Facebook" to the valid redirect url is now needed because Facebook made "Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs" enabled by default, and cannot be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that your Facebook App's settings are a bit off. You need to add your site's URL to your Facebook App's settings to prevent other sites taking advantage of your Facebook Login.

Here's how to do it:

1. Open https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
2. Click on your app
3. Open `Settings` from left-side menu
4. Click `Advanced` tab
5. Scroll to `Client OAuth Settings`
6. Fill in your site's URL to `Valid OAuth redirect URIs`

The URI should be the one that is sent to the Facebook when you're trying to log in with the plugin (you can find it from the address, probably something like `redirect_url`).

Comment: I did that, included the facebook.com part and what was after redirect_url

Comment: and white listed both, tried them separately and still wouldn't work.

Comment: Do you think it is the plugin?

Comment: So you added http://yoursite.com/something (from `redirect_url`) to `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` and the Facebook Login still gave you the same error?

Comment: Yes.  And from oauth.io I whitelisted the domain the login comes from.

Comment: Still not figuring this out.  the Plugin developers couldn't even help.  They said it was a problem on Facebooks end... Yith Plugins btw.  the one im dealing with it the WooCommerce Social Login

Comment: I am experiencing this issue also, redirect_uri matches exactly to the config in Client OAuth Settings - see more on developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/232085950706415 need help anyone.. thanks in advance