# Wordpress/WP Social Login error while logging into Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-login

If I am not logged into facebook on browser, then I was getting following error:

> You are not logged in: You are not logged in. Please log in and try
>   again.

If I am logged into facebook then I was getting below error:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

I was using WP Social Login plugin on Wordpress installation.

Below is the solution.

Comment: Its already sove here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001004/facebook-login-message-url-blocked-this-redirect-failed-because-the-redirect

Comment: the solution there didn't work for me which is why I added this. Cheers!

Comment: Late to the party - but here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948971/social-login-plugin-for-wordpress-not-working

Answer (score 0):

While implementing it on my website: http://www.mahol.pk, I was able to have facebook login working by doing following:

1) In the facebook app, create a 'Facebook Login' product by clicking on '+Add Product' on the left side panel.

2) Set the following settings in the 'Facebook Login':

[image: Client OAuth Settings]

Please note that I had to add both www and non-www URLs in Valid OAuth redirect URIs. Hope it helps anyone who gets this error. I was stuck with this issue for two days :)